# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setString(String) from the type MyString

Tags: java, string, static

I need to create a class for the methods described in the interface as follows:

```
public interface MyStringInterface {

    // Sets the value of the current string
    public void setString(String str);

    // Returns the current string
    public String getString();
}
```

When I create a class with methods as below, there is always this error and wont let me proceed. What am I doing wrong? How should I proceed?

```
package seclass.assgn;

public class MyString implements MyStringInterface{

    static String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        setString("This is my sentence");
        System.out.println(getString());
    }

    public void setString(String str){
        name = str;
    }
    public String getString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consult the thousands of other such questions, some of which you can find on your right, under the _Related_ section.

Comment: `setString()` and `getString()` are non-static methods, so they cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: One way to make this work is simply making your `name` non-static by removing the `static` modifier.

Comment: Read up on what static means.

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of `MyString` -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyString my = new MyString();            
  my.setString("This is my sentence");
  System.out.println(my.getString());
}
```

also

```
static String name;
```

should be

```
private String name;
```

Alternatively, if you don't want an instance just use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  name = "This is my sentence";
  System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't have to repeat "public" in interfaces.

```
public interface MyStringInterface {
    void   setString(String str);
    String getString();
} // end of class MyStringInterface
```

Then you must make an Object of your implementation:

```
public class MyString implements MyStringInterface {
String name;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyString().top();
}


void top() {
    setString("This is my sentence.");
    System.out.println(getString());
}


@Override
public void setString(String str) {
    this.name = str;
}


@Override
public String getString() {
    return this.name;
}

} // end of class MyString
```

Comment: Good! +1 for correct answer and for mentioning to not use the `public` keyword for interface members.

Comment: Even better would be, to separate the test-program from the implementation. But I think, that was not the question.